# UIAlertController action that doesn't dismiss view

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I've created a UIAlertController with a text field and an action to send a verification code to the user's phone number. However, the action dismisses the alert controller as well, making the user unable to enter the verification code. Is there a way to make an alert action not dismiss the alert controller?

```
   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Verification", message: "a code has been sent to your phone number", preferredStyle: .alert)

let confirm = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default, handler: {
    alert -> Void in
    //verifies code
})

let resend = UIAlertAction(title: "Resend", style: .default, handler: {
        alert -> Void in
        //resends code
    })

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: {
    (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

})

alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
    textField.placeholder = "Enter code"
}

alertController.addAction(confirm)
alertController.addAction(resend)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: share some code

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919670/prevent-uialertcontroller-to-dismiss

Comment: Try https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView

Comment: Why didn't you make custom AlertController by taking UIView and do whatever you wanted. All things are in your hand like when you wanted to present dismiss and all. Even its no too hard and time cunsuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate) and [isEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertaction/1620109-isenabled) property of [UIAlertAction](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertaction) to achieve the desired effect.

**Steps:**

1. Your class should confirm to `UITextFieldDelegate`
2. Your alert's action should be declared as a class level property
3. Disabled the alert action before displaying the alert
4. Configure the textfield and set delegate as your class
5. Implement `shouldChangeCharactersIn:` method
6. If text length is greater than desired length enable the alert action, else disable the alert action

**Code:**

```
// Your Class should confirm to UITextFieldDelegate
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    // Verify alert action, alert button that want to be disabled
    var verifyAction : UIAlertAction!

    // Shows the alert
    @IBAction func showAlert(sender : UIButton)
    {
        let alert    = UIAlertController(title: "Verify", message: "Please Enter the verification code to continue", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        verifyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Verify", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in
            // Do verification and other stuffs
        }

        // Configures textfield properties and delegate
        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Verification Code"
            textField.delegate    = self
        }

        // Disables the button
        verifyAction.isEnabled = false
        alert.addAction(verifyAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Textfield delegate method for observing the text change
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
        // if text length is greater than 0 enables the button, else disables it
        let existingText = textField.text as NSString?
        if let replacedText = existingText?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string), replacedText.characters.count > 0
        {
            verifyAction.isEnabled = true
        }
        else
        {
            verifyAction.isEnabled = false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

**Note:**
I wrote this answer before you posting the code, so it was not based on the code you provided with your question. It's a generic answer, I'll edit the answer if you want me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

By using the default alert controller, on tapping any of the alert action button will dismiss the alert controller. You may have to create your own custom view/viewcontroller and perform the corresponding action or use some third party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code, because this works fine to me :

```
func createAlert() {
    // initializing
    let alertControler = UIAlertController(title: "Your Title",
                                           message: "Your message",
                                           preferredStyle: .Alert)
    // create actions
    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .Default, handler: {
        (action) -> Void in self.confirmAction()
    })

    let resendAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Resend", style: .Default, handler: {
        (action) -> Void in self.resendAction()
    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: {
        (action) -> Void in self.dismissAlert()
    })

    // add actions
    alertControler.addAction(confirmAction)
    alertControler.addAction(resendAction)
    alertControler.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertControler, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// initiate this func to your class
@objc private func dismissAlert() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@objc private func confirmAction() {
    // yuor action here
}

@objc private func resendAction() {
    // your action here
}
```

And just implement self.createAlert() to your main action. Or implement "self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)" to your cancelAction