# Prevent UIAlertController from dismissing on UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I am working on one of the application where i am promoting user for force update using `UIAlertController` in which i don't wanted to allow user to perform any activity until and unless he updates the application from AppStore.

To achieve this i have written following code.

```
if (needToUpdate)
{
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Version Available", message: "There is a newer version available for download! Please update the app by visiting the Apple Store.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(
        UIAlertAction(
            title: "Update",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
            handler: { alertAction in
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "https://itunes.apple.com/app/cheapo-casino-free-casino/id637522371?ls=1&mt=8")!)
                alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }
        )
    )
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

It is working good but whenever user presses Update button it will go to app store and if user don't update the application. he/she will come back to application and can perform any activity which is not expected.

Is there any way to show the `UIAlertController` even if user press update button?

Comment: FYI - Apple really doesn't want apps doing what you are doing. Let a user decide whether they want to update or not. Personally I hate apps that force me to update when I don't want to.

Comment: Although I basically agree with the above comment, I have to ask: If you don't want it to close, why are you calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated`?

Comment: May be this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919670/prevent-uialertcontroller-to-dismiss

Comment: @PhillipMills The call to `dismissViewController` is pointless and shouldn't even be there. You can't prevent an alert controller from being dismissed once a button is tapped. It's dismissed automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the version of the app in appDelegate.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
     //check the app version here and if version mismatch is there show the alert.
     // if the version is different then make initial viewController as root view controller. and then present alert from that view controller.
}
```