# Disable the auto dismissal of the alert when tapping on a button

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

```
func showAlert(...) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(...)

    let add = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in
        onAdd?()
    }

    alertController.addAction(ok)

    ...
}
```

I would like to keep the popup alert after click on `Add`. But it seem iOS will auto close the popup. How to make it work?

Comment: If you don't want it dismissed, it may be easier to do with just a set of views that you hide or show as part of the underlying view controller logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent dismissal of UIAlertController](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25628000/3687801)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to prevent a UIAlertController's alert from being dismissed when a button is tapped is to *disable* the button.

If you don't like that, don't use UIAlertController; use your own presented view controller. That's all a UIAlertController is, after all. So it's easy to write your own if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just showing this alert again in handler of UIAlertAction. So when user clicks button in alert, it closes and just opens again. In my implementation click on the alert button redirects user to AppStore where he should update the app, so if he will return to the app again - he will still see this alert again.