# How to use Swift Selector? Selector constantly results to `Type has no member`

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, selector, nstimer

I'm struggling with the following piece of code:

```
backgroundTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: gvc, selector: #selector(GameViewController.addNext), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I can't seem to get the #selector working. This code results to:

```
Type 'GameViewController' has no member 'addNext'
```

Even though the member is right there... Here's the full code:

```
class GameViewController: GAITrackedViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate  {

    var sceneCanvas: SKSpriteNode?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       skView.presentScene(WelcomeScene(size: view.bounds.size, gvc: self))
    }

    func createBackground(boundsSize: CGRect, gvc: GameViewController) -> SKSpriteNode {
       addUILabels(gvc)
       return sceneCanvas!
    }

    func addUILabels(gvc: GameViewController) {
        backgroundTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: gvc, selector: #selector(GameViewController.addNext), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    public func addNext() {
        let backgroundLabel = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "label1.png")
        sceneCanvas!.addChild(backgroundLabel!)
        backgroundLabel?.runAction(SKAction.moveByX(-screenSize.width , y: 0, duration: 12))
    }
}

class WelcomeScene: SKScene {
      init(size: CGSize, gvc: GameViewController){
        super.init ()
        let bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0), size: size)
        sceneCanvas = createBackground(bounds, gvc: gvc)
        self.addChild(sceneCanvas!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just try #selector(addNext).

Comment: Try: #selector(GameViewController.addNext(_:))

Comment: @Muhammad Yawar Ali #selector(GameViewController.addNext(_:)) results to ` 'GameViewController' has no member 'addNext`

Comment: @gagarwal #selector(addNext) results to `Ambiguous use of 'addNext()'`

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @R P Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175)

Comment: @user594883 try `#selector(addNext as Void -> Void)`

Comment: @ElCaptain  when I do that xcode tells me that `Argument of '#selector' refers to a method that is not exposed to Objective-C` and offers to Fix-it by adding @objc infront of the method. If I do that xcode tells me `@objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes`

Comment: My suggestion is to check if the method `addNext` is contained within `GameViewController` class. You might have accidentally wrote it outside `GameViewController` class. And all the errors that you have specified points to that one potential issue.

Comment: Another possibility is the `addNext` method is within another method

Comment: @RP You were right! It wasn't my ignorance but my stupidity that caused the issue. In fact I had misaligned brackets that caused the method to be outside the class. THANK YOU!!!! And Thank you all for leaving answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that two things were the problem. 1) I had defined the method outside the class, 2) However also the following syntax was needed for it work:

`selector: #selector(addNext as () -> ())`

Comment: this worked for me also. Can somebody explain why all other ways did not work

Answer (score 8):

I was running into this issue with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and Swift 3.

I had my method in an extension for a long press on a table view cell:

```
// Long press table view extension
extension MyViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

     public func handleLongPress(longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

         let p = longPressGesture.location(in: self.tableView)
         let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: p)

         if indexPath == nil {
             print("Long press on table view, not row.")
         }
         else if (longPressGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began) {
             print("Long press on row, at \(indexPath!.row)")
         }   
     }
 }
```

Then, in my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
     // Configure long press on tableviewcell
    let longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.handleLongPress))
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
    longPressGesture.delegate = self
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
```

For me, the issue was fixed by using this syntax for the selector:

```
action: #selector(MyViewController.handleLongPress)
```

I tried the following alternatives without any luck. **These do not work**:

- ```
  action: #selector(self.handleLongPress)
  ```
- ```
  action: #selector(MyViewController.handleLongPress(_:))
  ```
- ```
  action: #selector(self.handleLongPress(_:))
  ```
- ```
  action: #selector("handleLongPress(_:)")
  ```

Additionally, even though I don't seem to be passing any arguments to `MyViewController.handleLongPress`, the selected row prints out to the console just fine on long press selection:

`Long press on row, at 5`

Comment: Exactly as you described. The 4 alternatives did not work--only passing the class's name worked. I also needed `@objc` in front of the selector function's name.

Answer (score 2):

```
backgroundTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("addNext"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: This results to  `Use of unresolved identifier 'self'`

Comment: backgroundTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: gvc, selector: Selector(gvc.addNext), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)...try this

Answer (score 2):

Probably your code is in different modules. If so you should make your `func addNext()` public:

```
public func addNext() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is. I added public but it didn't resolve the issue. Edited code above.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this.

```
backgroundTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.addNext), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

or

```
backgroundTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: gvc, selector: #selector(gvc.addNext), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Stubborningly this refuses to work. First one results to `Use of unresolved identifier 'self'` and the second `Value of type 'GameViewController' has no member 'addNext'`